# How do I run the Ubuntu startup command with commands to run within Ubuntu on the same line?

Tags: boot, command-line, execute-command

I can run `./start-ubuntu.sh` in my (Android emulator) terminal and then run my commands `cd code-server-4.5.2-linux-arm64 && cd bin && export PASSWORD="pass" && ./code-server` separately and they function, but is there a way to run these commands with the command that starts Ubuntu?

[Commands run separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHIUQ.png)

[Attempting to run all commands together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRavN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Please don't put screenshots of a terminal in the question. Always copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly into the question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the [edit question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423993/edit) window.

Comment: Thanks,  @user68186. PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"